# CloudFunction deploy: " error Parsing error: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When trying to deploy my cloudfunction with: `firebase deploy --only functions` I get this error:

> 22:24  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token user

This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addFriend = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    let user = db.collection('user');
    let friend = await user.where('email', '==', data.email).get();

    if (friend != null) {
        console.log(friend.data()['id']);
    }
});
```

The error links to the line with `await user.where...` I did stuff like this before and it worked. I can't see what I am doing different.

Anyone sees my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `await`, you have to declare the enclosing function as `async`:

```
exports.addFriend = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
```